# JavaScript parsing value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

While clicking the submit button of the following form,

```
<form id="message-form" action="#" method="post">
    <div class="text-middle">
        <?php foreach($result as $row) { ?> 
            <button class="button button1" value="<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>" onclick="myFunction(this)"><?php echo $row['Id']; ?></button>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

the `value` is sent to the function

```
window.onload = function() {
    var messageField = document.getElementById('message');
    var messagesList = document.getElementById('messages');
    var form = document.getElementById('message-form');
    var message = messageField.value;
}
```

But it showing only same value for every click

Comment: There is no element in your HTML with an id of `message`, hence `messageField` is undefined.

Comment: You call a function named `myFunction`, and you look for id's `message` and `messages` but there are no matching references. You might have to post the whole code to get help

Comment: <button class="button button1" type="submit" id="message" value="<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>" onclick="myFunction(this)"><?php echo $row['Id']; ?></button>  Use this code in html but no change

Answer (score 0):

The "window.onload" function fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading. That is the reason your getting same values.

I think you have to call myFunction and not window.onload.

Comment: What values do you see?